# Code causes infinite loop in start function of Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was wondering how I would avoid an infinite loop by running this code within the start function in unity.

```
    void Start ()
    {
        Room[] rooms = generateRooms();

        int falseCount = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!rooms[i].separationFlocking(rooms)) {
                    falseCount++;
                }
            }

            if (falseCount >= rooms.Length) break;
        }

    }
```

`separationFlocking` returns false if the object didn't need to be moved, so if `rooms.Length` number of objects weren't moved then I want it to break the while loop. Although, everytime I compile it, it never seems to compile to play mode, presumably because of the infinite loop.

```
    void Update ()
    {
        
        int falseCount = 0;

        if (falseCount != rooms.Length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!rooms[i].separationFlocking(rooms)) {
                    falseCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

If I run similar code in the update function it seems to work fine, so I know that detecting if the object didn't move isn't broken.

[image]

When I run the start function with a iterator that breaks after 100 loops I get this result. The cubes seem to separate from each other in odd ways, spreading out from their original circular arrangement.

[image]

This is how they're supposed to turn out and they successful do so in the update function. Although, I want to avoid running this code every frame for performance reasons.

This whole project is based on [this](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/procedural-dungeon-generation-algorithm) blog post. Also here's the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/p0RQRJqF) link so you can see the whole code. If you want to run it in unity all you need to do is add it to an empty game object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method continously? I would call it only when needed. If you one to lower the call frequency you can space that call in the update, or use a corroutine. Not debugged examples below.

frequency execution control in the update:

```
float elapsedTime = 0f;
int runFreqTime = 2; //to run every 2 seconds
void Update ()
{
    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    if (elapsedTime > runFreqTime) {
        int falseCount = 0;

        if (falseCount != rooms.Length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!rooms[i].separationFlocking(rooms)) {
                    falseCount += 1;
                }
            }
        }
        elapsedTime = 0f; //time control float reset
    }
    
}
```

coroutine:

```
public void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(RepetitiveExec());
}
IEnumerator RepetitiveExec()
{
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!rooms[i].separationFlocking(rooms)) {
                falseCount++;
            }
        }

        if (falseCount >= rooms.Length) break;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
}
```

Need to be careful with coroutines. It would be executing until you [Stop](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html) it

Comment: Adding a coroutine to start still causes an infinite loop because it still wont enter playmode. I only need to run the code once at the beginning of the program in order to properly place the cubes.

Comment: corouteines run on a separated thread so the call will execute on. "I only need to run the code once at the beginning of the program in order to properly place the cubes" -> then I do not understand the purpose of the question. If you only need to execute the code onlt once, just dont wrap your `for` loop in the `while(true) {}` and that is it. wil only run once at the `Start()`

Comment: maybe you need to show what `separationFlocking` does. Can it be that as it keeps running the cubes are separated further every time. If that is the case, instead of using a ´while(true) ´ I would try running that logic for a determined amount of times: `for (int times = 0; times < 1000; i++) {}` starting with a random value, 1000 for example, and tweak that until the desired behaviour is achieved

Comment: The number of loops are pretty much a random amount. I don’t think there’s any easy way to calculate it. I left the code in a pastebin link in my post if you want to take a look.